# James not sending emails to foreign server

Tags: email, james

community 
I already installed James in my machine. I configured it. I did a telnet on 4555 port and I added several users. Then I did a telnet on 25 port, and I sent a mail to an outside email address like this

```
ehlo leo@localhost
...
mail from: <leo@localhost>
250 2.1.0 Sender <leo@localhost> OK
rcpt to: <lroura@uci.cu>
250 2.1.5 Recipient <lroura@uci.cu> OK
data
354 Ok Send data ending with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
subject: otr prueba
jejejejje
.
250 2.6.0 Message received
```

In leo inbox appears a message like this

```
Return-Path: <>
Delivered-To: leo@localhost
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 14:04:29 -0500 (GMT-05:00)
From: postmaster@localhost
To: leo@localhost
Message-ID: <33108879.3.1445454269196.JavaMail.root@mypc>
In-Reply-To: <23978087.1.1445454269122.JavaMail.root@mypc>
Subject: Re:otr prueba
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report;
    boundary="----=_Part_2_22845834.1445454269146";
    report-type=delivery-status

------=_Part_2_22845834.1445454269146
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi. This is the James mail server at mypc.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.  Below
I include the list of recipients and the reason why I was unable to deliver
your message.

Failed recipient(s):
lroura@uci.cu

Error message:
554 5.7.1 <unknown[10.31.105.115]>: Client host rejected: Access denied


------=_Part_2_22845834.1445454269146
Content-Type: message/delivery-status; name=status.dat
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Description: Delivery Status Notification
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=status.dat

Reporting-MTA: dns; mypc
Received-From-MTA: dns; localhost

Final-Recipient: rfc822; lroura@uci.cu
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 <unknown[10.31.105.115]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 14:03:58 -0500 (GMT-05:00)

------=_Part_2_22845834.1445454269146
Content-Type: message/rfc822; name="otr prueba"
Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="otr prueba"

Message-ID: <23978087.1.1445454269122.JavaMail.root@mypc>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1])
          by mypc (JAMES SMTP Server 2.3.2) with SMTP ID 269
          for <lroura@uci.cu>;
          Wed, 21 Oct 2015 14:03:58 -0500 (GMT-05:00)
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 14:03:58 -0500 (GMT-05:00)
From: leo@localhost
subject: otr prueba
jejejejje



------=_Part_2_22845834.1445454269146--
```

What can I do in order to send an email to a outside server using James?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Leandro Roura Sixto: Hi. Basically the SMTP error code 554 is thrown when the receiver identifies your machine as a source of SPAM or a relay host. This is typically caused by the domain of leo i.e. localhost. Add some meaningful host like gmail or yahoo, you will be able to get through the SPAM Filter of the receiver's mail server/ SMTP.